# Unhandled Rejection (Error): The shape of dict['image_tensor'] provided in model.execute(dict) must be [X,X,X,X], but was X,X,X]

Tags: tensorflow, tensorflow.js, tensorflowjs-converter

**TensorFlow.js version**
v1.5.2

**Browser version**
Chrome 79.0.3945.130

**Describe the problem or feature request**
I trained my own object with the tensorflow 1.15.0 with faster_rcnn_inception_v2_coco_2018_01_28. After that saved model was converted web models with tensorflow converter. tensorflowjs version is 1.5.2.

This created model using web app error The shape of dict['image_tensor'] provided in model.execute(dict) must be [X,X,X,X], but was [X,X,X]

Create saved model

```
python export_inference_graph.py --input_type image_tensor --pipeline_config_path training/faster_rcnn_inception_v2_pets.config --trained_checkpoint_prefix training/model.ckpt-XXXX --output_directory inference_graph
```

Convert saved model

```
tensorflowjs_converter
--input_format=tf_saved_model
--output_node_names='MobilenetV1/Predictions/Reshape_1'
--saved_model_tags=serve
/mobilenet/saved_model
/mobilenet/web_model
```

tensorflowjs web app

```
const img = document.getElementById('img');
const model = await tf.loadGraphModel('model.json')
model.predict(tf.browser.fromPixels(img)) // or model.predict(img)
```

What is wrong this process ?

Answer (score 0):

It is a shape mismatch error.

It seems that the model is expecting a 4d tensor whereas you are supplying a 3d tensor. `expandDims` or `reshape` can be used to add a new dimension to the 3d tensor used as argument

Answer (score 0):

This error may occur because the model expects a batch of images rather than only one image. To fix it, one can insert the extra dimension using [`expandDims`](https://js.tensorflow.org/api/1.5.1/#tf.Tensor.expandDims).

```
const output = model.predict(tf.fromPixels(image).expandDims(0));
```